# How can I attach a click handler for multiple IDs and identify the ID within the handler in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm very new to jquery and what would be a simple way to do this:

My server side code spits out html like this:

```
<div name="destinationName" id="1">NEW DELHI</div>  
<div name="destinationName" id="2">JAIPUR</div>

<div name="destinationContent" id="1" style=";">NEW DELHI details</div>
<div name="destinationContent" id="2" style="display:none;">JAIPUR details</div>
```

By default `New Delhi` details needs to be shown. When I click on `Jaipur`, I'd like to display `Jaipur` details instead. When I click on `New Delhi` again, I need to only display `New Delhi` details. The behavior is similar to jquery tabs.

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[name="destinationName"]').click(function(){
        $('div[name="destinationContent"]:visible').hide();
        $('div[name="destinationContent"][id=this.id]').show();
       });
});
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H8rAD/)

When I click on `Jaipur`, both New Delhi and Jaipur are rendered. When I debugged through the code,

> $('div[name="destinationContent"][id=this.id]').show();

`this.id` is what is causing the problem.

**How can I refer this.id in the above script ??**

**PS**: If I replace this.id with "2", it works fine. In the console, when I output `this'id', it returns "2". So, I'm not sure how to resolve this.

---

Also, can someone recommend me a good way to group similar divs (I'm using names to group similar divs and ids to identify an element within that group) ?

Comment: you cannot have repeating `id`, you should instead use `class` or use custom attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly the `id` is a [*unique* identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute) and by having multiple elements with the same ID can cause undesired behaviour in jQuery. Secondly, `id` cannot (validly) start with a number unless your page has the [HTML5 doctype](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html#the-doctype).

So onto the problem you are having...

To use the element `id` in the selector you need to access it outside of your selector string and concatenate the result with the rest of the selector, otherwise it's just part of the string. The error you are seeing is correct that JavaScript doesn't know what `this.id` is, so the following change should correct the error:

```
$('div[name="destinationContent"][id=' + this.id + ']').show();
```

However, this does not correct the duplicate `id` problem. It would be better to use a unique class attribute for each *pair* to link the `<div>`s together.

You can also take advantage of the *class* attribute on the destinationContent instead of the custom *name* so that your jQuery selectors are easier to write (*class* selectors can be accessed using the (dot) `.`), for example in [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/69Jes/)

If the details are always in the same order as the titles then you can use the *index* of the element to simply select the same *destinationContent* as the title, for example:

**Edit:** Updated code with alternate solution not relying on element index.

#### HTML

```
<h3 class="delhi">NEW DELHI</h3>
<h3 class="jaipur" >JAIPUR</h3>
<hr/>
<div class="destinationContent">
    <div class="delhi">NEW DELHI details</div>
    <div class="jaipur">JAIPUR details</div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    var contents = $('.destinationContent div');
    contents.hide();

    $('h3').on('click', function(){
        contents.hide();
        $('.destinationContent div.' + this.className).show();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. I cannot rely on the order of details, so what alternative would you recommend to `$(this).index()` ?

Comment: Also, can you elaborate a bit on `It would be better to use a unique class attribute for each pair to link the <div>s together.`

Comment: Sure, I'll update my answer. I meant that, since `class` attributes can be duplicated, you could have `class="destination1"` for both the title and details and just use the class of the title clicked on to find the corresponding content

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternate solution, linking the title and related content together with a `class` attribute

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Numeric Id's isn't a good idea.

Secondly, Give your divs Id's in the following format:
MyDiv-1
MyDiv-2 and so on

Then, user

```
$("[id^='MyDiv']").click(function(){ ... });
```

This will hook event on all the divs that have Ids starting from MyDiv

Finally, in the click function

```
var id = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];
```

This will give you numeric id in variable id. You can use that to decide which div to show and which div to hide

You can further automate by giving your contect similar ids such as 'MyContent-1' and so on

Then you can simply append the id to "MyContent" and call show()

```
$("[id^='MyContent']").hide()
$("#MyContent-"+id).show()
```

Comment: What's a better approach, using "destinationContent-1" as id or using custom attributes ? PS: See charlietfl's response.

Comment: @brainydexter both will work but I would recommend that you use Ids. It can allow you to select any specific div based on its Id as well (in case you need it later on).

Answer (score 1):

You can't repeat ID's in a page and ID's should not be numeric in html4

Am changing the ID in first set of DIV's to a `data-` attribute, also changing `name` to class

```
<div class="destinationName" data-id="1">NEW DELHI</div>  
<div class="destinationName" data-id="2">JAIPUR</div>
```

JS

```
$('.destinationName').click(function(){
     /* change other "name" attributes to class */
     $('.destinationContent').hide();  
     var id= $(this).data('id');
     $('#'+id).show();
 })
```

Comment: which approach is better, `data-id="1"` or using `id=destinationContent="1"` ?

Comment: the `data-` attributes can be named whatever you want, just match them in  jQuery data('attributeName')

Comment: looking at other comments regarding index , this is likely your simplest route

Answer (score 0):

Never repeat id and therefore i have not used any attribute and made this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[name="destinationName"]').click(function(){
$('div[name="destinationContent"]').hide();        
$('div[name="destinationContent"]:contains('+this.innerHTML+')').show();

       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain the `:contains('+this.innerHTML+')` construct here ?

Comment: it will select the div with name(destnationcontent) whose html contains destinationName content

Comment: won't all the other div also have destinationName content ? (and this would then select and show others too ) ?

Comment: But they dont contain specific innerHTML .By the way is it working or not

Comment: no that didn't work, and if I understand this correctly, it will always search for the html content of destinationName in detinationContent's html, which may/may not be true.

Comment: yeah you are right this is somewhat hackish but using index() is not at all bad

Comment: yes, but can't rely on the order either. See UmairP and charlietfl's response

Comment: yeah but if you have not some serious problem then i will still recommend you in using index() as it will not require any extra attribute

Comment: what if the details are not in the same order as the names. I might end up displaying mismatched data

Comment: can i know why they will not be in same order